# Calling requestAnimationFrame causes animation to run faster

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Press the start/restart button several times and you'll notice that the speed increases. It's not meant to, the speed should just reset to '5'. Can't figure out whats wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/LQEkn/

The code for the start/reset button is at the bottom of the Fiddle:

```
//Start game function + button
function resetGame() {
    ball.x = board.width/2;
    ball.y = board.height/2;
    ball.xSpeed = 5;
    ball.ySpeed = 0;
    player1.score = 0;
    player1.newScore = false;
    player2.score = 0;
    player2.newScore = false;
}

startButton.onclick = function() {
    startButtonText.innerHTML = "Restart game";
    resetGame();
    renderPresentation();
    animate(step);
};
```

I've tried to stop the animation before calling it:

```
startButton.onclick = function() {
    startButtonText.innerHTML = "Restart game";
    resetGame();
    renderPresentation();
    var rid = animate(step); //animate is window.requestAnimationFrame()
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
    animate(step);
};
```

I've been staring at my code for too long, anyone up to take a quick look?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual speed of your ball is fine. However, your game runs twice as fast because every click on the restart button will call `animate(step)`. Since `animate()` is just a convenience wrapper for `requestAnimationFrame` you will end up with more animation/update steps than you originally intended.

The easiest solution for this is to check whether the game is already running and skip the `animate(step)` in this case ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQEkn/1/)):

```
startButton.onclick = function() {
    startButtonText.innerHTML = "Restart game";
    resetGame();
    renderPresentation();
    if(!game_is_running){
        animate(step);
        game_is_running = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! (The cancelAnimationFrame info was added to the question after your answer, however that did not solve the issue.)

Comment: @camelBase: That's because you're still *leaking* one `animate` call. At the end you would need to save your `rid` outside of that function and check whether it's `0`. If it's `0` you could clear the animation and use `animate` again, but there's not so much difference to `game_is_running` then.